# How to change metadata on an installed rpm

Tags: linux, rpm

I need to modify information for an rpm which is already installed.

E.g.

```
rpm -qi sip-section-call-1.0.19-1.noarch  
Name        : sip-section-call               Relocations: (not relocatable)  
Version     : 1.0.19                              Vendor: Self  
Release     : 1                               Build Date: Thu 08 Sep 2011 02:47:43 PM CEST    
Install Date: Mon 28 Nov 2011 03:31:09 PM CET        Build Host: ari.eris.com                        Group       : ari/JavaEE               Source RPM: sip-section-call-1.0.19-1.src.rpm  
Size        : 3929998                         License: Commercial    
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Tue 01 Nov 2011 01:25:59 PM CET, Key ID bdd82316c28e369d  
Packager    : ari  
Summary     : ari com Engine sip Service  
Description :  
Provides session id's for applications.
```

Here, I need to modify the Description to some other value
How do I do it?

Comment: rpm crash course: http://perso.b2b2c.ca/sarrazip/dev/rpm-building-crash-course.htm. hint: you need to look into the spec file.

Comment: @Oz123 He wants to modify the description of an *already* installed RPM.

Comment: Its a dbm file, so please take a copy before you venture into any sorts of edits to the file. Also, look at `--define` option of `rpmbuild` command.

Comment: This isn't supported by any common tool, because it's an extremely rare requirement. You may need to edit the database by hand, or perhaps explore changing some other file under `/var/lib/rpm` and running `rpm --rebuilddb`.

Comment: It probably isn't supported because it's the wrong thing to do. If a package needs fixing, fix the srpm, bump revision, rebuild, upgrade.